# Resizable Image Map with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, imagemap, resizable

Im working on creating a personal site, and I have a resizable image on my site. Im trying to use a plugin, linked [here](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps), and I can't seem to make it work. I copy pasted the Jquery from the GitHub site and still can't get it work. Here is my homepage HTML code.

```
<img src="contact.png" id="contact" height="862" width="1299" usemap="map1" alt="" />

<map name="map1">
  <area shape="rect" coords="178,268,285,373" href="http://twitter.com/TheCorbinLong" alt="twitterbox">
  <area shape="rect" coords="294,296,571,338" href="" alt="twittertext">
  <area shape="rect" coords="174,493,284,604" href="sun.htm" alt="instagrambox">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="instagramtext">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="http://youtube.com/gamersgearreviews" alt="ytbox">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="ttp://youtube.com/gamersgearreviews" alt="yttext">
  <area shape="rect" coords="173,721,283,832" href="http://medium.com/@TheCorbinLong" alt="blogbox">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="http://medium.com/@TheCorbinLong" alt="blogtext">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="mailto:corbin@long-family.org?Subject=Contact%20Info%20Page" alt="emailbox">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="mailto:corbin@long-family.org?Subject=Contact%20Info%20Page" alt="emailtext">
</map>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();

  });
</script>
```

I get an error message in the console as well, saying...

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps()')
    (anonymous function) (homepage.html, line 50)
    c (jquery.min.js, line 4)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 4)
    ready (jquery.min.js, line 4)
    q (jquery.min.js, line 4)
```

Also, I have this code resizing the image.

```
display: none;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 15px;
top:18%;
left: 20%;
right: 20%;
height: auto;
width: 60%;
overflow: scroll;
```

I can't seem to figure out how to have image map resize and can't understand the error message. I am also very new to Jquery. Also, If there is a better way to have the map resize rather what I am doing, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Resizeable, or responsive? Two different things.

Comment: If the latter, I've implemented this with good results. No scripting needed. http://demosthenes.info/blog/696/Using-SVG-as-an-Alternative-To-Imagemaps

Comment: @isherwood Im not sure of the difference. Im fairly new to all this. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be something related to the order in which you call the scripts. I have used it previously, and it works pretty well. Try this:

```
    <script src="jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or https://jsfiddle.net/